# Scaling a watermark to fit parent image

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing, watermark

My photo sizes vary, they are either landscape, portrait or square, and I need to make a watermark the best fit for each photo - so I need to resize just the width of the watermark (without Imagick), as it's a long rectangle shape, so height doesn't matter.

I found the PHP function, `imagecopyresized`, but I'll be honest, I can't work out what parameters are needed for my situation, even after looking at PHP documentation! I'm also not sure if after using imagecopyresized, the rest of my function will work where it gets the watermark width and height.

Can somebody help me get over the finish line. This is how far I got, all it needs is the right parameters added to the `imagecopyresized` part:

```
<?php

header('content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://.....jpg');
$imageSize = getimagesize('https://.....jpg');

$newWatermarkWidth = $imageSize[0]-50; // width of image minus 50px
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');

// resize watermark to newWatermarkWidth here with imagecopyresize
$watermark = imagecopyresized(?,?,?,?);

$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);

$dest_x = ($imageSize[0]/2) - ($watermark_width/2) ;
$dest_y = ($imageSize[1]/2) - ($watermark_height/2);

imagecopy($image, $watermark, round($dest_x,0), round($dest_y,0), 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);

?>
```

---

**THIS IS WHAT I ENDED WITH & WORKS PERFECTLY**

A script that adjusts the width of a watermark to fit across the whole parent image, centered and proportional.

```
<?php
header('content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://mydomain.com/myPhoto.jpg');
$imageSize = getimagesize('http://mydomain.com/myPhoto.jpg');

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('http://mydomain.com/myWatermark.png');

$watermark_o_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_o_height = imagesy($watermark);

$newWatermarkWidth = $imageSize[0]-20;
$newWatermarkHeight = $watermark_o_height * $newWatermarkWidth / $watermark_o_width;

imagecopyresized($image, $watermark, $imageSize[0]/2 - $newWatermarkWidth/2, $imageSize[1]/2 - $newWatermarkHeight/2, 0, 0, $newWatermarkWidth, $newWatermarkHeight, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));

imagejpeg($image);

imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This resizes the watermark and copies directly to the image.

You don't need the existing imagecopy line anymore.

```
$success = imagecopyresized($image,                 // Destination image
           $watermark,                              // Source image
           $imageSize[0]/2 - $newWatermarkWidth/2,  // Destination X
           $imageSize[1]/2 - imagesy($watermark)/2, // Destination Y
           0,                                       // Source X
           0,                                       // Source Y
           $newWatermarkWidth,                      // Destination W
           imagesy($watermark),                     // Destination H
           imagesx($watermark),                     // Source W
           imagesy($watermark));                    // Source H
```

Comment: Thank-you very much Etan. This worked, however, the height of the watermark didn't scale very well. It appears to have stretched the width of the watermark but left the height behind a bit, and that has caused the position of the watermark to be a little higher than central. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed the vertical positioning bug (destination Y was wrong. use $imageSize[1] there)

Comment: Ahh. I didn't mean it like that, sorry. I wanted it to be resized proportionally. What I meant was the height of the watermark was tiny, so I wouldn't ever need to set that to a specific height, as the photo will always be bigger.

Comment: Ok, the Y positioning is perfect, thanks for the edit. I still need to work out how to keep the watermark height proportional.

Comment: Maybe that can be done at the top where I have calculated the new watermark width. If so, I can probably do this myself and have a **$newWatermarkHeight** value to your **imagecopyresized** function.

Comment: I managed to calculate the new proportional watermark height and works as intended. Thanks again.