# Scaling font size in php gd

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I am scaling the font size of text in a image so that the text string fills the image width. I do this by using imagettfbbox to determine the current text box width. This is what I am doing now:

```
//original image width and height
$size = getimagesize($this->image_path);
$size_x = $size[0];
$size_y = $size[1];

$font     ='font/arialbd.ttf';
$fontsize = 12;
$bbox   = imageftbbox($fontsize, 0, $font, $Watermarktext);
$tbwidth = $bbox[2];
$factor = round(($size_x / $tbwidth), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

// increase the font size to fit into the image
$fontsize = $fontsize * $factor;


$bbox   = imageftbbox($fontsize, 0, $font, $Watermarktext);             
$watermark_x = $bbox[2] - $bbox[6];
$watermark_y = $bbox[3] - $bbox[7]; 


$watermark = imagecreate( $watermark_x , $watermark_y );
```

By using this code the watermark that I am creating is still not exact. On a small image, the text still does not completely cover all of the width.

For better understanding this is the complete code:

```
$font     ='font/arialbd.ttf';
$fontsize = 12;
$bbox   = imageftbbox($fontsize, 0, $font, $Watermarktext);
$tbwidth = $bbox[2];
$factor = round(($size_x / $tbwidth), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

// increase the font size to fit into the image
$fontsize = $fontsize * $factor;


$bbox   = imageftbbox($fontsize, 0, $font, $Watermarktext);             
$watermark_x = $bbox[2] - $bbox[6];
$watermark_y = $bbox[3] - $bbox[7]; 


$watermark = imagecreate( $watermark_x , $watermark_y );
imagesavealpha($watermark, true);
imagealphablending($watermark, false);
$transperant = imagecolorallocatealpha($watermark, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefill($watermark, 0, 0, $transperant);

$background = imagecolorallocate( $watermark, 32,255,255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha( $watermark, 132,15,153,1);
imagecolortransparent($watermark, $background);
//apply string to watermark image         
imagefttext($watermark,$fontsize,0,-$bbox[6], -$bbox[7],$text_colour,$font,$Watermarktext);

// apply watermark to image
imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $watermark_x, $watermark_y);
```

Why does the same string not cover every width?

Comment: what is `$size_x` in `$factor = round(($size_x / $tbwidth), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);`

Comment: $size_x is the width of original image

Comment: you can use the following code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693644/scaling-a-watermark-to-fit-parent-image